# Comparing two arrays of objects in javascript and replacing with new information

Tags: javascript

I'm making a webpage that gets ADSB flight information over websocket and then (eventually) will map this information. I'm trying to write a function that receives the new flight information as an array of objects, then compares the first string of each object in the new array (a unique aircraft code identifier) to the first string in every object contained in my webpages array of current aircraft. If I detect an aircraft I already know about, I replace the entire object for that aircraft with the new data I received, if I don't already know about this aircraft I add it to my array as a new aircraft. I'm sending two dummy aircraft with different identifiers over websocket every 2 seconds, the first data sent should trigger a new aircraft detection and add them to the array, but after that they should simply replace the data there with new data, not make the list any longer, since I never send more than the same 2 aircraft for testing purposes. My function just detects them as new aircraft every time and so my array is just getting very large very quickly. Not sure what to do here it seems to make sense to me.

Here's what the object I'm sending looks like...(in python)

```
AC = [
{"ICAO" : "12AE45D","CALL" : "UA445","LAT" : 40.9, "LON" : -74.6, "ALT" : 34650,"GS" : 432,"TAS" : 452,"IAS" : 266,"MACH" : 0.78,"ROC" : -896,"TRK" : 293.84,"HDG" : 290.039,"LIVE" : "0s"},
{"ICAO" : "17bE65D","CALL" : "UA315","LAT" : 40.6, "LON" : -74.2, "ALT" : 34650,"GS" : 432,"TAS" : 452,"IAS" : 266,"MACH" : 0.78,"ROC" : -896,"TRK" : 293.84,"HDG" : 290.039,"LIVE" : "0s"}
]
```

Here's what my array for all aircraft is initialized as

```
var AC = [{"ICAO" : "NULL","CALL" : "NONE","LAT" : 40.9, "LON" : -74.6, "ALT" : 34650,"GS" : 432,"TAS" : 452,"IAS" : 266,"MACH" : 0.78,"ROC" : -896,"TRK" : 293.84,"HDG" : 290.039,"LIVE" : "0s"}] //all aircraft
```

my function

```
socket.addEventListener('message',function(event){ //message handling parse JSON and add to AC list
var object = JSON.parse(event.data);
console.log(object.length);
for (i=0; i < AC.length;i++){
  var match = false;
  for (j=0;j<object.length;j++){
    if (AC[i].ICAO == object[j].ICAO){
      //flight already exists 
      match = true;
      AC[i] = object[j]; //replace with new data
      break;
    }
    //no match found, new flight added
    if (match == false){
      console.log("no match")
      AC.push(object[j])
      break;
    }
    
  }
  console.log(AC)
  }
});
```

If I log AC.length at each update you can see it increments each time. It should start at length 1 since I have a dummy aircraft in AC at start, then increase to 3 as I add two new aircraft but stop increasing after that as any new information only contains update to existing aircraft. It looks like it can't find a match

```
Initial AC Length: 1                     index.html:60:13
no match                                 index.html:80:15
AC Length: 2                            index.html:86:11
no match                                 index.html:80:15
AC Length: 3                            index.html:86:11
no match                                 index.html:80:15
AC Length: 4                            index.html:86:11
no match                                 index.html:80:15
AC Length: 5                            index.html:86:11
no match                                 index.html:80:15
AC Length: 6                                index.html:86:11
```

Looks like Kmoser's fix works. I had it setup that way before but it caused like an exponential increase in the size of my array but I must have had something setup wrong.

Comment: could you elaborate more. I think your function works for your use case

Answer (score 0):

You're testing things in the wrong order. I've switched it to first loop through the new incoming objects, and for each of them then loop through the current AC list to find a dupe.

If a dupe is found, it replaces that element and stops looping, otherwise it adds it once it's gone through all existing AC objects to determine that it's not a dupe.

```js
for (j=0;j<object.length;j++){
    for (i=0; i < AC.length;i++){
        var match = false;
        if (AC[i].ICAO == object[j].ICAO){
            //flight already exists 
            match = true;
            AC[i] = object[j]; //replace with new data
            console.log(`Replaced ${AC[i].ICAO}`)
            break;
        }
    }

    //no match found, new flight added
    if (match == false){
        console.log("no match")
        AC.push(object[j])
    }

    console.log(AC)
}
```